# Cordova/Phonegap command doesnt execute

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ubuntu, npm

I have a problem during my cordova/phonegap installation. I did every step in this [PhoneGap Tutorial](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu/)

But when I try to execute "$cordova create" I get the message "cordova: command not found". When I try to execute "$phonegap" nothing happens.

[image: console picture]

Any idea, what to do? 
How can I reinstall everything? How can I check my installation?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cordova do you have installed? The latest stable at this time is 5.4.1
You can check cordova version using the command 
`cordova --version`

If by any chance you ended up with this error after an update, you can try uninstalling Cordova globally using `-g`(global) flag and install again using `sudo npm update -g cordova`

For steps regarding installation and update, please refer to the original documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)

You might need to create a fresh cordova project after installation/update and move your config preferences and www to the freshly created project/folder.